# symfony error when executing script cache clear

Tags: symfony

I tried to install symfony 7 with symfony cli and I had this error :

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!  
!!  In SecurityExtension.php line 94:
!!                                                                                 
!!    Enabling bundle "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle" and not conf  
!!    iguring it is not allowed.                                                   
!!                                                                                 
!!  
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

I just followed the symfony documentation installing & Setting up the Symfony Framework

symfony new my_project_directory --version="7.0.*" --webapp

and then run the app

cd my-project/

symfony server:start

Did someone allready have that kind of error?
thx!

Comment: The error is saying you should configure the bundle. have a look at your config/packages/security.yaml file. You are probably missing a configuration : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html

Comment: I stumbed upon this error too, while creating a new project using the Symfony CLI.
It appeared that I had a Github token issue with Composer. In the end, it may be an issue with Symfony Flex recipes not being properly installed.
Nicolas Grekas just opened a PR to improve the error message: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/53684

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `composer symfony:recipes:install symfony/security-bundle`

It should install the demanded recipe. However, it might be that your project is missing more Symfony Flex recipes. In that case, you may want to run `composer symfony:recipes:install` (without arguments)